# How can I make a choice from a <select> populate the title tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these selects:

```
$('#AccountID, #PageID, #TopicID')
    .focus(function () {
        $('option[value="99"]', this).remove();
        store.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
    })
    .change(function () {
        store.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
        $('#detailData').html("");
    });
```

Is there a way I can make it so that if a users select from the drop down that the Title attribute of the select is populated with the text from the option that the user selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you are asking for exactly, but Im guessing you mean something like this [example Ive made?](http://jsfiddle.net/tBa6b/)

html:

```
<p id="title">1</p>
<select id="dd">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$('#dd').change(function() {
  $('#title').text($(this).val());
});
```